# Edmx file is not under TFS source control VS2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I was having some issue with a relationship not showing up in an the Model Browser for a table. So I deleted it in the EDMX diagram and added it back.

Now I noticed when Checking In Pending Changes, that this same file was marked for deletion and that it is missing the source control padlock icon next to it.

[image]
 1. I tried `File > Source Control > Advanced > Refresh Status` to no
   avail.
 2. The rest of the project is fine...just this one file, so the
   source control Bindings check is all ok.
 3. I went up to the EDMX file and `r-click > Add files to source control`..again no luck.

Is there anyway to add this to source control again?

Comment: Does the file exist on the disk?

Comment: @bit Yes it does exist on the disk. And I can open it in VS2012.

Comment: Possibly, the file has been `Excluded` while checking in. Can you check the Excluded files section in Team Explorer and promote the file from there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can follow this link on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181392(v=vs.90).aspx):

This let you go to `Team Explorer => Source Control Explorer => Add Items To Folder => Then Select you .edmx file`.

Then that file is included in source control afterwards.

Alternatively, in `Check-In` Process, check if the file is in the `Excluded List` at the bottom of that pane.